# JavaScript inner object key with a string having space .?

Tags: javascript

I have a json object in the below format and am trying to retrive the **grade** for the key "**krishna kk**" which gives me an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [` error. can any one help to understand how to get the inner object data where the key name has spaces in it.

```
[
    {"studentinfo": [
            {
               "rama nathan": {
                    "grade": "1",
                    "roleno": "9",
                    "score": 9
                }
            },
            {
                "krishna kk": {
                    "grade": "3",
                    "roleno": "9",
                    "score": 4
                }
            },
            {
                "john Doe": {
                   "grade": "2",
                    "roleno": "5",
                    "score": 7
                }
            }
        ],
    }
]
```

My code as below :

```
var stugrade = studentobject["0"].studentinfo["0"].[rama nathan].grade;
```

Comment: Quote the key name!

Comment: And remove the dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute it like this

```
var stugrade = studentobject[0].studentinfo[0]['rama nathan']['grade'];
```

Comment: To avoid type casts, it is better to specify a numeric value:

var stugrade = studentobject[0].studentinfo[0]['rama nathan']['grade'];

Comment: any help how to get the Student name also.? (i.e. i want to fetch "rama nathan") to out put into html.

Answer (score 0):

Change `[rama nathan]` to `["rama nathan"]`. It's the way to call a JavaScript object property. Use it like this:

```
 var stugrade = studentobject["0"].studentinfo["0"]["rama nathan"].grade;
```

Comment: Why is it that i get an error when i try to execute this

Comment: Just rm dot here ["0"].["rama nathan"]